# Cosmos DB transactional Batch

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How do I execute a select statement (Select Product from Products Where ProductID =8 ) and the perform a insert to the db in a Transactional batch statement for Cosmos DB using .net/ c#

Is there any workaround to run a select statement as a part of batch before inserting a document to cosmos DB.

I could not find how to use transactional Batch to replace my existing stored proc. having select as well as insert statements.

My Stored Procedure:

-BEGIN
line 1 : Read the data from Db and take count of Products. For ex: returns 12 products.

Line 2 : Some further logic.

Line 3 : Insert record to the same table with a counter log of products ie. 12+1, returned from line 1.

-END

Now the problem that I will face if I move the first statement out of the SP , Maybe 2 or multiple instances can request the same line and get it executed . And the result I will have is Duplication of log number in products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't enlist a query into a transaction. The way to do this is to read the data then use optimistic concurrency control on the update with the etag on the item. You can find a sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/TransactionalBatch/Program.cs#L174)

Comment: By reading before the transaction I am falling into a situation where multiple calls to the same function in production result in same Count of products , so the further transaction insert is adding  duplicate log number in DB. Added more elaboration on Stored procedure in the question

Comment: Using eTag to check if the value is updated help me get to my solution here. many thanks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKtmntnhR58